# Xcode 4 - svn problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode4

So I created a new project wrote some code and now I just imported my project into my svn server. I just checked out the project and I am getting this message

> **'Test_project'is locked for editing and you may not be able to save
>   your changes. Do you want to unlock it?**

when I click on unlock I get this message.

The file “myusername.xcuserdatad” could not be unlocked.

I cant even locate this file. Has anyone else had this problem?
Please help. I'm totally new here

Answer (score 0):

`myusername.xcuserdatad` is a directory inside the `xcodeproj` bundle.  Right click the `.xcodeproj` file in Finder and select "Show Package Contents".  In there will be a directory called `xcuserdata` nd the subdirectory you need will be under that.  It may be enough to delete that directory (also delete it from Subversion) to resolve your issue (make sure Xcode is closed when you do this).

Answer (score 0):

1. check the svn status of this file/folder, go into the work folder
2. if the status it's "K", then it's be locked. (check commend:"svn status -v")
3. input "svn unlock " + your file name , to unlock the file.